# How to convert percent encoded string to UTF-8 encoded and create directory using the UTF-8 string

Tags: linux, utf-8

I have a percent encoded string: `%DB%81%DB%8C%D9%84%D9%88/`
I convert it to an `UTF-8 encoded string` by copying hexadecimal bytes (`%hh` -> `0xhh`).

UTF-8 encoded string: `str = U+00DB U+0081 U+00DB U+008C U+00D9 U+0084 U+00D9 U+0088`

And in Octal: `\333\201\333\214\331\204\331\201`

But the name of created directory is `Û ÛŒÙ„Ùˆ` (something garbled) rather than `یلو/`. I know that in Linux we can create directory with name in any language (Urdu, Chinese, etc. if the name is encoded in UTF-8)

Also, locale of machine is set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Any idea ?

Thanks @kmkamplan, I also used almost same logic to do byte by byte copy and still directory name is garbled. If on your system directory name is `یلو/` then I think some issue with charset settings. My charset/encoding is set to en_US.UTF-8. Please help me with this strange behavior. Thanks.

I am getting:

0000cd0 3034 3639 4a20 6e61 3120 2038 3631 333a

0000ce0 2034 81db 8cdb 84d9 88d9 000a

0000ceb

Please refer to comment below. Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer to indicate that you should check that your terminal is not the broken link.

Comment: I checked using your logic and my logic of percent encoded to UTF-8 conversion. Output i am getting in both the cases is same, i.e.: 0000ce0 2030 81db 8cdb 84d9 88d9 000a
0000ceb , Using GDB I checked hex values stored in UTF-8 string say str, p/x str[21] and so on... Found that it is storing correct hex value byte by byte but terminal is showing incorrectly. I suppose something wrong in my terminal. WIll try using xming now. Also, /bin/echo -e "\0320\0224\0320\0260\0041" gives me garbled output instead of Да!. So i guess something wrong with my terminal only.

Comment: To be sure can you please give above /bin/echo command in your terminal to see if you see correct output (Да!). Thanks

Comment: Issuing `echo -e "\0320\0224\0320\0260\0041"` does give `Да!` in my UTF-8 terminal. The symptoms you describe suggests that your terminal is not configured to display UTF-8 but some other form of character set. Probably ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @kmkaplan: Thanks a lot for your help and speedy response. Many things cleared. Problem left to be resolved is related to my terminal, rest everything working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is confusion between UTF-8 and Unicode. Decoding `%DB%81%DB%8C%D9%84%D9%88` will give you the *bytes* `0xDB 0x81 0xDB 0x8C 0xD9 0x84 0xD9 0x88`. Apparently this is an *UTF-8* encoded string consisting of arabic characters. If you read this as UTF-8 and decode it into Unicode code points you get:

- `0xDB 0x81` → U+06C1 Arabic letter heh goal (`ہ`),
- `0xDB 0x8C` → U+06CC Arabic letter farsi yeh (`ہی`),
- `0xD9 0x84` → U+0644 Arabic letter lam (`ل`),
- `0xD9 0x88` → U+0648 Arabic letter waw (`و`).

This is not to be confused with what you are actually decoding into:

- U+00DB Latin capital letter U with circumflex (`Û`),
- U+0081
- U+0084
- U+0088
- U+008C
- U+00D9 Latin capital letter U with grave (`Ù`),

Furthemore, Unix filenames are actually composed of *bytes*, not characters. So this is up to you to choose how to display them.

So the easiest way for this case is probably to do the percent decoding into bytes, and create your directory using those bytes as filename, *without* translating them into actual Unicode characters.

Here is an example that works:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>

const int hex_value[256] = {
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0,10,11,12,13,14,15
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::string str("%DB%81%DB%8C%D9%84%D9%88");

  size_t t = 0;
  for (size_t s = 0; s < str.size(); s++) {
    if (str[s] == '%' && s + 2 < str.size()) {
      str[t] = hex_value[str[s+1]] * 16 + hex_value[str[s+2]];
      s += 2;
    }
    else
      str[t] = str[s];
    t++;
  }
  str.resize(t);

  mkdir(str.c_str(), 0755);
}
```

If you still see other stuff than `ہیلو` on your terminal, it could be your terminal that is confused as to the character set it should use. To clear up this possible confusion, pipe the output of `ls` through `hexdump` and make sure that you see the bytes you are expecting:

```
$ ls | hexdump
0000000 61 2e 6f 75 74 0a 63 6c 65 61 6e 2e 70 68 70 0a
…
00000c0 32 32 2e 63 6f 6d 3a 32 32 0a db 81 db 8c d9 84
00000d0 d9 88 0a                                       
00000d3
```

Here you can clearly see the correct filename `db 81 db 8c d9 84 d9 88 0a` at the end.

Comment: Precisely, but how to convert 0xDB 0x81 → U+06C1 Arabic letter heh goal (ہ), etc...?? byte by byte copying which I am doing is decoding as U+00DB (as you rightly mentioned)

Comment: @user1989504 how are you currently decoding the percent encoded string?

Comment: Also, I have read that UTF-8 strings can be input to mkdir and no need to convert it into Unicode. ICU mailing list have said that ICU library is not needed to convert to Unicode. Just UTF-8 string is all that ia needed to create a directory on linux. On windows, I am converting this UTF-8 string to Unicode using ICU library and directory is created successfully.

Comment: Pls refer to code: " http://liveworkspace.org/code/3ycsWK$10" , this is to convert from percent encoded to utf-8 byte by byte. Each byte say DB is converted to hexadecimal and then %DB is replaced by the hexadecimal number.

Comment: @user1989504 that URL can not be accessed. The domain name liveworkspace.org does not work: its DNS name servers are not answering.

Comment: I think link is not working anymore. Please look at below code: while ((pos = str.rfind('%')) != std::string::npos) {
      uint8_t byte = (to_hex(str[pos+1]) << 4) | to_hex(str[pos+2]);
      str.replace(pos, 3, 1, byte);
   }, where to_hex convert each character into hexadecimal

Comment: uint8_t to_hex(uint8_t in) {
   if (in >= '0' && in <= '9') {
      return in - '0';
   }
   if (in >= 'A' && in <= 'F') {
      return in - 'A' + 10;
   }
   return in - 'a' + 10;
} Please note that same logic is working fine on windows, the UTF-8 string which I get from above function is then converted to Unicode using ICU library and _wmkdir creates directory properly